# I search to implement function get most occurence character in string and count it

Tags: java, arrays, string, data-structures

```
public class GFG  
{ 
    static final int ASCII_SIZE = 256; 
    static char getMaxOccuringChar(String str) 
    { 

        int count[] = new int[ASCII_SIZE]; 



        int len = str.length(); 
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) 
            count[str.charAt(i)]++; 

        int max = -1; 
        char result = ' ';   


        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
            if (max < count[str.charAt(i)]) { 
                max = count[str.charAt(i)]; 
                result = str.charAt(i); 
            } 
        } 

        return result; 
    }
```

I stopped here and can't count the most repeated character.

Comment: Without hash map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should be iterating over the characters in the `count` array and not the string contents. You already counted them. Also the `result` will be the character represented by the value of `i` so you can just cast `i` to a `char`. Lastly unless you want to count spaces you should ignore character `32` (a space) and possibly other white-space characters or they may end up being the most common character.  Here's a version that will count the most repeated character:

```java
class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GFG s = new GFG();
        char c = s.getMaxOccuringChar("People say there is nothing like a banana cream pie");
        System.out.println("Max char is " + c);
    }

    static final int ASCII_SIZE = 256;

    static char getMaxOccuringChar(String str) {

        int count[] = new int[ASCII_SIZE];

        int len = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            count[str.charAt(i)]++;

        int max = -1;
        char result = ' ';


        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if (max < count[i] && i != 32) {
                max = count[i];
                System.out.println("Max: "+max+" char: "+(char)i);
                result = (char)i;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This will print out:

```
Max: 0 char: 
Max: 1 char: P
Max: 6 char: a
Max: 7 char: e
Max char is e
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop you need 
`for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)` 
instead of 
`for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)`

and then `count[i]`instead of `count[str.charAt(i)]`

and finally `result = i` instead of `result = str.charAt(i)`